# Can you tap your Dryad Arbor for mana if there is a humility in play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Do land creatures like [Dryad Arbor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dryad%20Arbor) lose their mana abilities with [Humility](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Humility) in play?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it loses them if you look at the rulings on both cards.

[Humility](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Humility)

Card Text

> All creatures lose all abilities and have base power and toughness 1/1.

Gatherer Ruling

> Removes all creature abilities. This includes mana abilities. Animated lands will also lose the ability to tap for mana.

As can be seen Humility removes the ability from animated lands and Dryad Arbor is considered both a land and a creature. Because of this Humility will remove all abilities which includes tapping for mana.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I figured it would be helpful as they added it to the rulings for a reason. I can remove it if it is felt that it should be.

Comment: I find that ruling on Humility you quote to be confusing/misleading. "Removes all creature abilities" makes it sound like it might be excluding the ability that it has because it's a land. "Removes all abilities from all creatures" is clearer.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Removed that ruling.

Comment: @GendoIkari I added the card text in addition to the ruling.

Comment: What is this trend of answering with only rulings? 99% of questions can be answered with rules refs.

Comment: @Hackworth What exactly is wrong with that? It provides an answer and most people don't need a deep dive into the rules and what section it comes from.